# Getting all th tags and testing values with playwright

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, integration-testing, playwright

I'm using playwright to test a page, and I have the following table.

[image]

I want to be able to test all the thead th columns, the count and values are in the right order, i.e. Product, Price etc.

How would I go about doing this?

Here is what I've tried so far, although overkill

```js
test('the table headings are in place and in the correct order', async ({
      page,
    }) => {
      log('looking for the table headings...');

      const tableThead = page.$$('table.subscriptions > thead > tr > th');

      const allThs = await page.$$eval(
        'table.subscriptions > thead > tr',
        (ths) => {
          return ths.map((th) => {
            const product = th.querySelector('th:nth-child(1)');
            const price = th.querySelector('th:nth-child(2)');
            const term = th.querySelector('th:nth-child(3)');
            const renewalDate = th.querySelector('th:nth-child(4)');
            const renewalAmount = th.querySelector('th:nth-child(5)');
            const renewalType = th.querySelector('th:nth-child(6)');
            const paymentType = th.querySelector('th:nth-child(6)');
            const address = th.querySelector('th:nth-child(7)');
            return {
              product,
              price,
              term,
              renewalDate,
              renewalAmount,
              renewalType,
              paymentType,
              address,
            };
          });
        }
      );

      log('taking a screenshot...');

      await tableThead.screenshot({
        path: 'screenshots/subscriptions/table/table-head.png',
      });
    });
```

=======

Edit 1:

This is what I get after trying Alapan Das's answer:
[image]

Comment: Please add the code that you tried and the error that you are facing.

Comment: Added some code @AlapanDas

Answer (score 2):

I think for this case you can use the [locators lists](https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#lists) and then compare the inner texts like this:

```js
const expectedText = [
  product,
  price,
  term,
  renewalDate,
  renewalAmount,
  renewalType,
  paymentType,
  address,
]
const tableHeader = page.locator('th[role="columnheader"]')
const tableHeaderTexts = await tableHeader.allTextContents()
await tableHeaderTexts.forEach((text, index) => {
  expect(text).toEqual(expectedText[index])
})
```

Comment: Getting an error, I've added an edit to my question